# Rewrite from home.php to home

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite this url:

```
www.example.com/home.php to www.example.com/home
```

I write this code in the .htaccess but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home$ $home.php [nc]
```

why ?

Comment: `$home.php`? That ain't right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ home.php [nc]
```

SHOULD work. Did not test.

Comment: only home.php, not every *.php :)

Comment: Will actually cause a rewrite loop.  Don't escape the $ and limit the contents  of `(.*)` to a character set that won't include `.php`.  Or use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `!-d`